# getting an error while trying to pick a directory using expo document picker in react-native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, android-intent, expo

hay guys, i am making a react native app with expo and i am using "expo document picker" module to access the folder in the device by clicking on the button in my app , i am getting this error in my terminal --

```
LOG  [Error: Encountered an exception while calling native method: Exception occurred while executing exported method getDocumentAsync on module ExpoDocumentPicker: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT cat=[android.intent.category.OPENABLE] typ=directory }]
```

this is my code---

```
const pickDirectory = async () => {
    console.log("hi!!!!!");
    try {
      const permission =
        await FileSystem.StorageAccessFramework.requestDirectoryPermissionsAsync();
      if (permission.granted) {
        const dir = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({
          copyToCacheDirectory:true,
          type: "directory",
        });
        // setSyncDirectory();
        console.log(dir);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you are seeing is because the `DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync()` method can't find an app on your device that can open a folder.

The `DocumentPicker` module is meant for selecting and opening documents, not folders. If you want to let users choose a folder, you can use `FileSystem.StorageAccessFramework` instead. This allows you to request access to a directory and perform file operations like reading and writing files.

```
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';

const pickDirectory = async () => {
  console.log("hi!!!!!");
  try {
    const permission = await FileSystem.requestDirectoryPermissionsAsync();
    if (permission.granted) {
      const dir = await FileSystem.StorageAccessFramework.browseForFolderAsync();
      console.log(dir);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Note that the `browseForFolderAsync()` method is currently only available on Android, so if you need to support iOS as well, you will need to use a different method or library to allow the user to select a folder.

Comment: FileSystem.StorageAccessFramework.browseForFolderAsync(); this browseForFolder function is not avilable in FileSystem

Comment: Are you on android or IOS?

Comment: i am on android